# Array error in Constant Contact PHP API

Tags: php, arrays, constantcontact

I'm trying to automatically add a contact to a Constant Contact list when a form is submitted and have started with the addOrUpdateContact sample code that uses Constant Contact v2 API. I'm getting the following error when I submit the form:

```
Catchable fatal error: Argument 3 passed to Ctct\Services\ContactService::addContact() must be of the type array, boolean given, called in /home/cspacetribeca/public_html/mh/test.php on line 65 and defined in /home/cspacetribeca/public_html/mh/vendor/constantcontact/constantcontact/src/Ctct/Services/ContactService.php on line 131
```

The line referenced is:

```
$returnContact = $cc->contactService->addContact(ACCESS_TOKEN, $contact, true);
```

And ContactService.php, on line 131, does ask for an array:

```
public function addContact($accessToken, Contact $contact, Array $params = array())
```

How do I fix this?

Thanks - Joe

Comment: Why are you passing `true` if it expects an array?  Pass an array!

Comment: may be, if you don't have any additional params, just skip that `true` ? or set this `true` into `$params` array() accordingly ? ...

Comment: `true` is a boolean value, not an array... So why are you wondering why it's not working? The code explicitly states it wants "X", and you're stuffing in "Y" and getting rejected.

Comment: I guess what baffled me is that this is some official example code working directly with the official API. As written, there's no way it could work, is there?

Comment: You are using an older `ContactService.php`.  You can see in [this diff](https://github.com/constantcontact/php-sdk/commit/10ca6dd572a1de9101e654fe932f7d02dc8f8616) that the definition of the `addContact` function was changed from taking an array to a boolean/flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grab an updated version of the [ConstantContact SDK](https://github.com/constantcontact/php-sdk) (I have no affiliation with this project).  You can see from [this diff](https://github.com/constantcontact/php-sdk/commit/10ca6dd572a1de9101e654fe932f7d02dc8f8616) that it was updated December 2015 with a change that included a modified definition of the `addContact()` function.  So you are likely referencing updated "official example code", but still using the old SDK.

The definition was changed from

```
public function addContact($accessToken, Contact $contact, Array $params = array()) {
```

to

```
public function addContact($accessToken, Contact $contact, $actionByContact) {
```

Comment: Thank you! I used Composer to get the latest version, but I guess I was still a version behind.